# Can you start a brand new character?

Tags: trove

So my dad has started playing Trove (with his own account), and I'd like to be able to play along with him through the early game, but my lowest level class is my knight at level 5.

Is there any way I can restart one of my classes / somehow set them back to level 1?

Comment: Assuming you've been playing the beta for a bit now, have you already used the second beta key from glyph? I know a week or two back they gave everybody another one so they could invite friends to the game. You could use that to give your dad his own account, then you could play together :p

Comment: @slow_excellence He already has his own account, my issue is that my characters are all too high level to play with him properly early-game.

Comment: Ahh, fair enough

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, this has not yet been implemented in the game. You might want to try contacting support to see if this might be done in your case, but there is no way currently to do this by yourself.

Comment: "yet" sounds like wishful thinking. I don't think that with their "squeeze the last penny out of a customer" pricing model they are interested in doing it at all. You get what you paid for. The usual support response would be that you are welcome to buy a new class in the in-game store, or create a new account for the same class.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you could buy a new class. New classes are always at level 1. However, if you've bought all the classes, why don't you stuff the current gear in a chest and go hunting for basic equipment? The stats will go down, and you'll be stuck with two jumps again, but it's not all that bad!

Otherwise, you can play on the PTS server (I think) to reset all that everything.

Comment: Stats gained through levelling XP still contribute a significant amount to your HP/damage/etc.